# Как лучше перевести "golden bridge"

Tags: перевод

Как лучше перевести "golden bridge" в следующем отрывке:

> The writings of Thakur Bhaktivinode provide the golden bridge by which the mental speculationist can safely cross the raging waters of fruitless empiric controversies that trouble the peace of those who choose to trust in their guidance for finding the Truth.

Мой перевод

> Труды Бхактивинода Тхакура - это золотой мост, по которому ментальный спекулянт может безопасно пересечь бушующие воды бесплодных эмпирических споров, нарушающих покой тех, кто в поисках Истины выбрал твердо верить в их руководство.

Я не нашла, чтобы это выражение относилось к устойчивым. Слово "golden" может переводиться как "прекрасный" или "отличный", но это также мало помогает. Может быть "крепкий", но это как кажется уже совсем вольный стиль.

Comment: "ментальный спекулянт"???

Comment: "Mental speculationist" is something like "склонный к умозрительным построениям/теориям".

Comment: @Matt умозрительный философ

Comment: I believe one who speculates (theorizes) is a "speculator", not a "speculationist" in English, and the whole construct seems to some kind of a Sanskrit calque. Anyway, "golden bridge" here seems to be just *золотой мост* (unless it's idiomatic in Sanskrit).

Comment: очень плохой перевод, честно говоря

Comment: Попробуйте спросить на http://ell.stackexchange.com . Там людей то побольше, скорей всего объяснят получше

Comment: Я бы выбрал словосочетание "надёжный мост".

Answer (score 1):

The word 'golden' in this particular piece doesn't hold any meaning other than emphasizing the quality of the 'bridge', perhaps holding the meaning 'best', as in

> 'the writings provide the best way there is for the mental speculationist to cross the raging waters of fruitless empiric controversies that trouble the peace of those who choose to trust in their guidance for finding the Truth'.

So the translation isn't a word-by-word one like you've presented, it's more to do with the meaning of the phrase itself. So, translating freely, it could be

> 'Труды Бхактивинода Тхакура - лучший способ для...'
>
> 'Труды Бхактивинода Тхакура - наилучший путь для...'

or

> 'Труды Бхактивинода Тхакура как нельзя лучше позволяют...'

Comment: Мне кажется, что если бы автор хотел так сказать "the best way", он бы так и сказал, тем более, что владел английским в совершенстве. Статья написано почти 100 лет назад, может быть это было какое-то устойчивое выражение того времени, которое означает "лучший способ", но хотелось бы не отходить от оригинальной манеры изложения.

Answer (score 1):

В предложении бесплодные эмпирические споры сравниваются с бушующими водами, а труды Тхакура - с золотым мостом, по которому можно пересечь их.  В переводе, чтобы сохранить метафору, надо brigde перевести как мост, и никак иначе.  Golden bridge - это золотой мост, тем более что как "золотой мост", так и "golden bridge" широко используются, когда говорят о йоге (легко нагуглить).

Comment: Статья не о йоге, и даже если попытаться связать ее каким-то образом с йогой, то по крайней мере совсем не о той йоге, с которой это выражение связывается в интернете. Но в любом случае я согласна с вами, потому что упоминаются "бушующие воды". Хотя выражение "золотой мост" не звучит. Может быть выражение "надежный мост" звучало бы лучше, как упомянул @user6667, но я не знаю, стоит ли отходить от выражения, употребленного автором этой статьи.

Comment: О какой-то индийской/восточной мистике.